# Run robolectric and android unit test from Android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I currently have various `AndroidTestCases` which use `Mockito` and the module `dexmaker-mockito`. I am now trying to add `Robolectric` test cases using the `robolectric plugin`.
I have everything running fine except that when I try to mock methods with no arguements I get an `IllegalArgumentException` from `Dexmaker`. Removing the `dexmaker-mockito` dependency and using mockito version `1.9.0` instead of `1.9.5` causes the error to go away but causes all of my AndroidTestCases to fail. Is there anyway in `gradle` to have `dexmaker-mockito` exclude from my `robolectric` test cases? Or does anyone know of any other way to run both android unit test and robolectric unit test from android studio?

`Error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.InvocationHandlerAdapter.invoke`

**Update**

I tried `gradle-android-test-plugin` and `robolectric-gradle-plugin` but was unable to to get rid of the `IllegalArguementException` without changing the version of `mockitio` to `1.9.0` and removing `dexmaker`, `dexmaker-mockito` from my dependencies.

I tried the [guide](http://tryge.com/2013/02/28/android-gradle-build/) but was unable to get Android Studio to recognize my source directories without adding them to main or test source sets which break my build because robolectric is not compiled for those gradle tasks and I do not want it to be.

I ended up following the guide [here](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/android-gradle-app-with-robolectric-junit-tests/) this time the error disappeared when I ran the tests from command line but persisted when running from android studio which I found odd. Again changing the version of mockitio to 1.9.0 and removing `dexmaker`, `dexmaker-mockito` from my dependencies in my Android App removed the error. For now I will settle for not being able to run the unit tests from android studio until I find a better answer.

Comment: where is the code???????

Comment: My code is a bit complicated given the example I will try write up a simple app sometime and post it.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem right now.

Comment: Well I tried again a few weeks ago and had more success with the https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test plugin. There is also the android unit test plugin for android studio which resolved alot of my other problems. However, it still ended up being unusable for me. Another option is to try the built in unit test in the beta version of android studio listed here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support. I haven't had the time try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what dexmaker-mockito is supposed to do, it's meant to be used with Android Unit Tests that run on device, so it's good for your Android Test Cases.

Robolectric tests run on the JVM and should be run as JUnit test, not Android tests. They should not be using dexmaker-mockito as they never get deployed to device, they can just use the normal Mockito libraries, with scope set to test.

I think you may not be able to mix the two, you may have two keep your robo tests separate from your Android unit tests.

Comment: So the only solution would be to have the test cases in separate modules? This causes the Robolectric plugin to fail.

Comment: It will be a lot easier for people to help you out if you update the question describing exactly what it is you have tried and what errors you have encountered, as you try out different solutions.

Comment: Sorry I went ahead and added what I tried and changed the question to more accurately reflect my issue.